# Não dar echo em uma row vazia IS NOT NULL

Tags: php

me deparei com um problema que não consigo contornar. A situação é a seguinte, criei um sistema de busca no mysql que resulta em marcações no mapa (Google Maps API) que criei.
O problema é que alguns dos clientes estão com os campos"lat" e "lon" em branco, e isso resulta em um erro no API do Google Maps, que fica todo em branco.
A ideia é que se algum cliente estiver com os campos "lat" e "lon" em branco, não de echo neste cliente. Assim não resultaria em erros no mapa. E os demais clientes com todos os campos preenchidos, daria echo normalmente.
Já tentei usar o IS NOT NULL, mas não funciona.
Código PHP:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM politicos WHERE name LIKE '%$busca%' OR info LIKE '%$busca%' AND lat IS NOT NULL");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$name = $row['name'];
$lat = $row['lat'];
$lon = $row['lon'];
$info = $row['info'];
echo("addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>Nome: $name</b><br />Informações: $info');\n");
}
```

Resultado do echo:

```
addMarker(, , '<b>Nome: Cliente 1</b><br />Informações: ');
```

isso resulta em erro no mapa

Resultado do echo se colocar 0 em lat e lon:

```
addMarker(0, 0, '<b>Nome: Cliente 1</b><br />Informações: ');
```

isso coloca o marcador na linha do equador :(

Não quero que de echo em clientes com os campos "lat" e "lon" vazios!
Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço muito!

Comment: `A ideia é que se algum cliente estiver com os campos "lat" e "lon" em branco, não de echo neste cliente.` veja bem, vazio e null são coisas diferentes. Os campos no bd recebem valores null, mesmo?

Comment: Tente adicionar parenteses nas condições que envolvem `like`, tipo `WHERE (name LIKE ... OR info LIKE ...) AND lat IS NOT NULL`. Aproveite e leia [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/5878).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar a função `empty`.

A função [empty](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) retorna FALSE para todos os itens abaixo:

> - "" (uma string vazia)
> - 0 (0 como um inteiro)
> - 0.0 (0 como um ponto flutuante)
> - "0" (0 como uma string)
> - NULL
> - FALSE
> - array() (um array vazio)
> - $var; (uma variável declarada, mas sem valor)

Ficaria desta forma:

```
<?php

/*...*/

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $name = $row['name'];
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lon = $row['lon'];
    $info = $row['info'];

    if( !empty($lat) && !empty($lon) )
    {
        echo("addMarker($lat, $lon, '<b>Nome: $name</b><br />Informações: $info');\n");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Nossa valeu mesmo! Funcionou, está retornando só os clientes que possuem $lat e $lon. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Existem diversas formas de verificar isso, dependendo do que retorna do banco. Para testar, use o `var_dump($row['lat']);` para identificar o tipo de retorno que possui.

Após identificar, algum desses casos abaixo deve te atender

```
if (isset($row['lat'])) {
  echo("addMarker....")
}
```

ou

```
if ($row['lat'] !== '') {
  echo("addMarker....")
}
```

ou

```
if ($row['lat'] !== NULL) {
  echo("addMarker....")
}
```

algo nessa linha...

Answer (score 0):

A forma apropriada, via PHP, é conforme respondeu o @BrunoRigolon.

Também pode resolver apenas na query SQL.

O problema é que NULL é diferente de vazio. e provavelmente os campos não estão como NULL e sim vazios.

Para dar consistência, faça a condição

```
(lat IS NOT NULL AND lat != '')
```

*O parênteses é necessário pois há duas condições.